# Increasing memory size with maven-exec-plugin

Tags: java, maven-2, heap-memory

I want to use maven-exec-plugin to run my class.

```
class ThisTestLauncher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(
        ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean().getHeapMemoryUsage().getMax()
    );
}
```

pom:

```
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
   <mainClass>com.my.ThisTestLauncher</mainClass>
   <arguments>
      <argument>-Xms512m</argument>
      <argument>-Xmx2g</argument>
   </arguments>
</configuration>
```

Still, I see output to be 259522560, that's like 256m size. 
The same result for

```
<commandlineArgs>-Xms512m -Xmx2g</commandlineArgs>
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: <commandlineArgs> are passed to the main method. This are no JVM arguments. The description about <arguments> in not very clear in the documentation. Are the passed to main method, too? Can you check this? As an alternative, use goal exec:exec and specify "java -Xmx512m -Xmx2g com.my.ThisTestLauncher" as your command to execute. See http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html

Comment: You are right, thanks

Answer (score 1):

`<commandlineArgs>` and `<arguments>` are passed to the main method. They are no JVM arguments.

As an alternative, use goal `exec:exec` and specify `java -Xmx512m -Xmx2g com.my.ThisTestLauncher` as your command to execute. See http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html